# Upload file (image) from local machine using shopify-api-node

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am trying to upload local images to a Shopify product via [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [shopify-api-node](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node).

This is the part of the code, where I am uploading the images.

```
product.images.forEach(async image => {
  Logger.toFile("product.image", image);
  try {
    await this._api.productImage.create(shopifyProduct.id, {
      src: image.src
    });
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.error("Error uploading images.");
    this._handleErrors(error);
  }
})
```

If I use an external URL for `image.src`, everything works just fine.

Here is the logger with working external URL:

```
[2022-02-01 16:44:38 UTC][Products] product.image {
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/220px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png',
  position: 1
}
```

And the not working local src:

```
product.image {
  src: '/Users/radoslav/Server/projects/tmp/pics/264-426.png',
  position: 1
}
```

The path is correct and the image `264-426.png` exists.

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong, or is it possible to upload an image to Shopify from a local link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to upload an image from a local relative path which is wrong at the moment.

But I'm not sure if the API handles local images with the proper path and even if you use absolute path.

The best approach will be to read the image with Node.js and convert it to `Base64` and pass it that way. You can refer to the docs here: [https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-07/resources/product-image#[post]/admin/api/2021-07/products/{product_id}/images.json](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-07/resources/product-image#%5Bpost%5D/admin/api/2021-07/products/%7Bproduct_id%7D/images.json)

In addition please note that `async/await` doesn't work in a `forEach` function. So at the moment you are stacking all the uploads at the same time and the API will not be happy.

**PS:** Give my regards to Zoro/Marto & Evgeni. ;)